# How to associate an input variable to a list name?

Tags: python, list, input

```
#my simple code
i_sm = input("Enter Scale (Major or Minor): ")
Major = [root,W,W,H,W,W,W]
Minor = [root,W,H,W,W,H,W]
print(i_sm)
```

I would like to associate the input variable `i_sm` to a list `Major` or `Minor`, and have the contents of that printed, e.g.  user input of "Major" would result in output of `root,W,W,H,W,W,W`.
However, the output generated is "Major". How can I get the actual list to print?

Comment: Store your lists in a dictionary, keyed on the scale name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do this.

You can store lists of values e.g. `['Mustang', 'Focus']` associated with a specific key e.g. `'ford'`. You can later retrieve the list of values for a given key using `cars['ford']` or `cars['tesla']` or `cars[choice.lower()]` if `choice` was a value input by the user.

```
cars = {
    'ford': ['Mustang', 'Focus'],
    'tesla': ['Model 3', 'Model S']
}

choice = input("Enter manufacturer (Ford or Tesla): ")

try:
    print(cars[choice.lower()])
except KeyError:
    print('Error: choose Ford or Tesla')
```

Note that I've converted the input value to lowercase so that users don't have to be too precise - they can enter `Ford`, `ford`, `FORD` and all will work.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a Python Dictionary

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

```
i_sm = input("Enter Scale (Major or Minor): ")

Major = ["root","W","W","H","W","W","W"]
Minor = ["root","W","H","W","W","H","W"]

aDict = { "Major": Major, "Minor": Minor}


print( aDict[i_sm] )
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked easily! And thank you to the link - very helpful!